# Don't save lightning logs in Pytorch Lightning

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, checkpoint

I'm running this code:

```
model = CIFAR10Classifier()
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=50, gpus=1, default_root_dir="..", enable_checkpointing=False)
# trainer.fit(model, train_dataloader, valid_dataloader)  

model = CIFAR10Classifier.load_from_checkpoint("../lightning_logs/cifar10_classifier/checkpoints/epoch=49-step=35150.ckpt")
model.eval()
# preds = trainer.predict(model, dataloaders=test_dataloader, return_predictions=True)
p = trainer.test(model, dataloaders=test_dataloader)
print(p)
```

When I'm running trainer.test, it's creating additional version_x folders inside the lightning_logs folder, which I don't want. Can I reuse them in any way? If not, then is there any way to disable it from creating?
Also, When I'm experimenting with the training loop, I don't want to save any checkpoint. Is there any workaround too for that?

Answer (score 1):

If enable_checkpointing=False does not help, try also setting logger=False:

```
trainer = Trainer(enable_checkpointing=False, logger=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [*disable checkpoint*](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/checkpointing_basic.html#disable-checkpointing) using the `Trainer` option [`enable_checkpointing`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/trainer.html?highlight=enable_checkpointing#enable-checkpointing):

```
trainer = Trainer(enable_checkpointing=False)
```

Or use a checkpoint to [*resume training*](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/checkpointing_basic.html#lightningmodule-from-checkpoint) with [`load_from_checkpoint`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/lightning_module.html?highlight=load_from_checkpoint#load-from-checkpoint):

```
model = MyLightningModule.load_from_checkpoint("/path/to/checkpoint.ckpt")

# disable randomness, dropout, etc...
model.eval()

# predict with the model
y_hat = model(x)
```

Comment: While testing also, it's saving checkpoints even after setting enable_checkpointing=False